# Gnuplotting changing axis basis

Tags: gnuplot

i've got a data set that is of a vector f(x,y,z). Formatted as fx fy fz x y. This data set is of a crystal lattice and it's associated reciprocal lattice. The coordinates x y  are in a non orthogonal basis. Such that x and y are unit vectors x=(1,0) y=(0.5,sqrt(3)/2). I'm trying to plot a set of 3 heatmaps one for each component of f. My issue is that I can seem to change the x and y axis such that they are the unit vectors above. Is there a way to make non-orthogonal/perpendicular axes in gnuplot? If not does anyone have any ideas on how to represent this data set?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is not change the axes, but apply a change of variable from your columns 4 and 5 to the cartesian coordinates x,y:

```
ex_x=1; ex_y=0
ey_x=0.5; ey_y=sqrt(3)/2
splot "file.dat" u (ex_x*$4+ey_x*$5):(ey_y*$4,ey_y*$5):1 with pm3d
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, So I actually hard coded this into the code. However doing it on the post-processing side is better.  http://imgur.com/a/VJd72 here is a link to two of the types of graphs in thier infant stages.  it's easiest to see on the vector plot. There is a ton of white space that detracts from the image. I was hoping that I could remove this, but I think I'm just going to have to draw bounding vectors around each cluster.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for. One hint though, if I understand correctly that vector `f` is zero in a large part of the plotting domain, you might want to have the vectors overlaid on a colourmap of the modulus `|f|`.

Comment: Or if it is the white triangles at top and bottom which are annoying, you can remove the border and draw your own custom axes with `set arrow` and a `for` loop for labels and tics.